# Setting Material UI's KeyboardDatePicker default value to state object property

Tags: material-ui, datepicker, default-value, date-fns

I am using Material UI v4 MuiPickersUtilsProvider with DateFnsUtils and am not able to set the defaultValue on the KeyboardDatePicker to the date of a state object property. Actually, I haven't been able to make it show anything other than today's date, even by providing an example string date directly.

My 'Task' (parent) component has a button that opens a Dialog to the 'Status' (child) component, to which it passes the Task by Id. The Task object has an array of Statuses. I am trying to set the most recent Status due date as the defaultValue in my date picker.

Here is an example of the task object being passed as props:

```
{
"id": 31,
"taskName": "Test task",
"originalDueDate": "2023-08-18T10:17:38.585",
"taskStatuses": [
{
"id": 61,
"taskId": 31,
"statusId": 1,
"statusDescription": "Task Created",
"statusDueDate": "2023-08-18T10:17:38.585",
},
{
"id": 70,
"taskId": 31,
"statusId": 1,
"statusDueDate": "2023-08-24T13:45:00",
}
]
}
```

Using this example, I would want the defaultValue to be 08/24/2023 from the taskStatus id 70.

Here is my useEffect on the child component:

```
useEffect(() => {
getStatusOptions();
if (props.task) {
setIsLoading(false);
console.log("tasks", task);
}
}, [props]);
```

Here is the DatePicker:

````
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
<KeyboardDatePicker
disableToolbar
size="small"
inputVariant="outlined"
variant="inline"
format="MM/dd/yyyy"
className={clsx(classes.dateField, classes.margin)}
name="statusDueDate"
label="Update Due Date"
value={taskStatus.statusDueDate}
onChange={(date) => handleDateChange(date, "statusDueDate")}
/>
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>```
````

Creating new statuses works fine with the date picker. To set the defaulValue, I have tried moment, formatISO, "2023-08-24", "08-24-2023", etc. I've tried all the same for initialFocusedDate. I've tried all kinds of conditionals, i.e.:

```
defaultValue={
props.task.taskStatuses.length &&
props.task.taskStatuses.length > 0
? moment(
props.task.taskStatuses[
props.task.taskStatuses.length - 1
].statusDueDate
).format("MM/DD/YYYY")
: null
}
```

What I am missing?